# PHP - preg_split html by line break or paragraph

Tags: php, html, preg-split

I have some html like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
Dolor sit amet
<br><br>
consectetur
<p>adipiscing</p>
<br>elit.
```

And I'm trying to split it in two parts and in the end, to get this:

```
Array(
    [0] => <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
           Dolor sit amet
    [1] => <br><br>
           consectetur
           <p>adipiscing</p>
           <br>elit.
)
```

The idea is to have the first array element containing either the first two "paragraphs". By "paragraph" I mean, either the text inside a "p" tag, or the text after two consecutive "br" tags.

Comment: You are example shows only double break `<br><br>` as delimiter, it doesn't consider `p` tag at all.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this pattern: `/(<\s*p\s*\/?>)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>)/` would help you? See the [demo](http://ideone.com/XOgWM)

Comment: Thanks. I used a variation of your code to split some really messed up HTML: `$parsed = preg_split('/(<\s*p\s*\/?>)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>)|(\s\s+)|(<\s*\/p\s*\/?>)/', $datatoparse, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to split a string by a string by the looks of it.  preg_split will split by a regular expression, although it is possible, I suspect it's not what you need.

Here's Splitting by two `<br>` tags

```
$my_string = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
Dolor sit amet
<br><br>
consectetur
<p>adipiscing</p>
<br>elit.';

$split_string = explode('<br><br>', $my_string);
```

This will output as an array

```
echo $split_string[0];
echo $split_string[1];
```

Comment: What language is that supposed to be? It ain't PHP ;)

Comment: Oops, Sorry I've got Javscript on the brain!  There you go, in PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure the s pattern modifier is necessary, but this should work, and capture the `<br><br>` in the 2nd value as specified.

```
$result_array = preg_split("/(?=<br><br>)/is", $my_string);
```